# Comparar los elementos de un array contra si mismo

Tags: java, algoritmos

Necesito recorrer un arraylist  y comparar cada elemento del array con todos los elementos del mismo array y saber cual se repite mas veces; tengo algo asi

```
  for (int x = 0; x < lista1.size(); x++) {

        int temp = lista1.get(x);

        for (int y = 0; y < lista1.size(); y++) {
            if (temp == lista1.get(y)) {

                System.out.println("temp"+temp);
                System.out.println(lista1.get(y));
                rep = rep + 1;
                lista3.add(temp);
                lista3.add(rep);
                rep = 0;
            }


        }
```

El problema es que me hace un for de cada uno y no me compara cada x con todo y . Y si tienen uan mejor idea de como hacerlo se los agradeceria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrás problemas cuando los elementos se repitan en la lista , tendrás doble total de repeticiones.

Para emplear un método iterativo , se podría tener dos variables , `repe` que será el total de repeticiones de un número en la lista , y k como indice para la lista auxiliar.

Iteramos sobre la lista, tomamos el elemento y iteramos en el segundo for donde la condición aparte del típico `i< n` también comparamos que la lista auxiliar no contenga `!contains` el elemento , porque si ya lo contiene quiere decir que es un elemento que ya se evaluó. *nos evitamos la iteración*

Al final del for interno comparamos que la cantidad de repeticiones sea mayor a 0 y si es así añadimos el elemento a la lista auxiliar, incrementamos el indice `k` , realizamos la impresión y luego reseteamos el contador a 0

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add(1);
lista.add(3);
lista.add(2);
lista.add(3);
lista.add(1);
lista.add(1);
int repe = 0;
int k = 0;
List<Integer> repetidos = new ArrayList<>();
for (int x = 0; x < lista.size(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < lista.size() && !repetidos.contains(lista.get(x)); y++) {
        if (lista.get(x).equals(lista.get(y)))
            repe +=1;
    }
    if(repe>0){
        repetidos.add(k,lista.get(x));
        System.out.println("EL ELEMENTO " + repetidos.get(k) + " SE REPITE "+ repe);
        k++;
    }
    repe=0;
}
```

Una forma sería emplear `Stream` , mediante el método [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) para realizar una reducción de la `lista` inicial , lo reducirá básicamente a una [Agrupación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) de clave , valor que serán asignados al `Map` , donde la clave será la palabra y el valor el total de repeticiones , para esto se emplea el método [counting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) de la clase [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add(1);
lista.add(3);
lista.add(2);
lista.add(3);
lista.add(1);
lista.add(1);
Map<Integer, Long> repeticiones = lista.stream().
collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting()));
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry : repeticiones.entrySet())
   System.out.println("Número : " + entry.getKey()+ 
         " , Se Repite : " + entry.getValue()+ " Veces");
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tiene varios problemas de lógica.

No entiendo porque dices que no compara todo x con todo y, porque es lo que está haciendo.

Sin embargo, al comparar todo de vuelta, cualquier repetición se te va a duplicar.

Fíjate que para este array: {1,1,2,2}

Va a comparar:

1 con 1 ok (contra sí mismo)
1 con 1 ok (el segundo 1)
1 con 2 no
1 con 2 no

Luego va al segundo 1
1 con 1 ok
1 con 1 ok (contra sí mismo)
1 con 2 no
1 con 2 no

Para hacer este tipo de cosas, siempre se compara para adelante. O sea desde la posición en la que estas, comparas siempre desde x+1, entonces evitas comparar con sí mismo, y también evitas comparar lo que ya comparaste.

Aparte, no deberías comparar un elemento que ya comparaste.. Una vez que revisaste el 1, no deberías revisarlo más.

Y para saber cuál se repite más veces, lo único que tenes que hacer es tener una variable con la cantidad de repeticiones, y luego comparar con la cantidad de repeticiones que encontraste para este caso...

Answer (score 1):

Con este método puedes contar cuantas veces se repite cada número.

```
      public void repetidos( ArrayList<Integer> listaAux){
ArrayList<Integer> listaAux=(ArrayList<Integer>)lista.clone();
            while (listaAux.size()>0) {
                int numVeces=0;
                int val=listaAux.get(0);
                for (int y = 0; y < listaAux.size(); y++) {
                    if(val==listaAux.get(y)){
                        numVeces++;
                       listaAux.remove(y);
                       y--;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("El número: "+val+" se repite: "+numVeces);    
            }
       }
```

### Método de Prueba:

```
  public void prueba(){
        ArrayList<Integer> lista1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lista1.add(1);
        lista1.add(1);
        lista1.add(1);
        lista1.add(1);
        lista1.add(2);
        lista1.add(2); 
        lista1.add(3);
        repetidos(lista1);
   }
```

### Salida:

> El número: 1 se repite: 4
>
> El número: 2 se repite: 2
>
> El número: 3 se repite: 1

Comment: Es una opción valida pero después del método la lista principal se quedará sin valores. _no creo que sea correcto esa parte_

Comment: Tienes razón, agregué una línea para solucionar eso.

Answer (score 0):

He hecho una función para obtener el total de repeticiones en una lista que puede servirte. En el siguiente ejemplo creo un bucle for para recorrer la lista "lista1", y compruebo con la función getRepeticiones las veces que esta repetido ese numero y lo saco por terminal.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> lista1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> lista3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    lista1.add(1);lista1.add(15);lista1.add(3);lista1.add(5);lista1.add(15);
    for (int y = 0; y < lista1.size(); y++) {
        System.out.println(getRepeticiones(lista1.get(y), lista1));
    }

}
static public int getRepeticiones(int valor,List<Integer> lista){
    int out = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
        if(lista.get(i)==valor){
            out++;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: estas contando las repeticiones tambien.. en que cambia este codigo conel de OP?

Comment: ya si lo se que también comprueba los numero repetidos. Después habría que filtrar el resultado para que no muestre las repeticiones.